# Calling functions DLL in Delphi error buffer

Tags: delphi, dllimport

I’ve got these 4 dll function probably created in c++ of which I have examples of calling these functions both in c ++ and in visual basic.

I have to use these functions in delphi (Delphi 7 and Delphi 10.4). VbOpen, VbClose, and VbWrite work just fine but I can't get VbRead to work.

I have already declared these functions as follows:

```
function VbOpen(_1: Integer;_2: LongInt;_3: BYTE;_4: BYTE;_5: BYTE;_6: BYTE;var _7: LongInt): Integer; stdcall;
function VbClose(var com:LongInt):Integer ; stdcall;
function VbWrite(var Command:AnsiString; var _3: LongInt): Integer;  stdcall ;
function VbRead(var pBufOut : PAnsiChar ; var nBufferSize : LongInt;var _3: LongInt): integer; stdcall;
//
Call to VbRead
r:=VbOpen(5,...,...,...,...,,.);
 if r=0 then
 begin
    //
    IpCommand := '1009'; 
    r:=VbWrite(IpCommand,errorCode);
    // Visual Basic
   GetMem(pBufOut,100);
    r:=VbRead(pBufOut, pByteRead, errorCode);
    if r=0 then
    begin
      if pByteRead > 0 then
      begin
        SetString(resultString, pBufOut, pdwByteRead);
      end;
    end;
end;
 
VbClose(errorCode); // Closes the connection and frees the used memory
```

The result of VbRead resultString are garbage characters but pByteRead bytes returned like a correct value.

Example in visual basic where I have the working exe file

```
Dim vReturn As Long
Dim vCodeErr As Long
Dim vRetByte As Long
Dim s As String
Dim strOut As String
Dim pBufOut(1000) As Byte
Dim i As Long

s = "1001" // comand code
vReturn = VbWrite(s, vCodeEr)
vReturn = VbRead(pBufOut(),vRetByte, vCodeEr)
' Close Com Port
vReturn = VbClose(vCodeEr)

i = 1
strOut = ""
While (i <= vRetByte)
    strOut = strOut + String(1, pBufOut(i))
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

From the user manual of the dll

Sintax DWORD VbRead(SAFERRAY** pBufOut, LPDWORD pByteRead, LPDWORD lpdwCodeError)

pBufOut  address of the bytes read
pByteRead  number of bytes read
lpdwCodeError system errors returned

Where is the error hiding?
Thanks for any help

Vincent

Comment: Do you have a C/C++ header file for this DLL? That would be easier to translate to Delphi than translating VB code.

Comment: DWORD CEFCallDllProc_004(CString strProcName, unsigned char *lpMemArea, LPDWORD NumByteRead, LPDWORD lpdwSysError);

Comment: that is not what I asked. But OK, if you have a working C/C++ example, then please show that. But FYI, `CString` is not portable to other compilers, or even safe to pass over the DLL boundary

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to use [VarArrayCreate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/fr/System.Variants.VarArrayCreate) to allocate space.

```
var
  Arr: Variant;
begin
  Arr := VarArrayCreate([1000], varByte);
```

Answer (score 1):

the VB example allocates 1000 Bytes. But you allocate with GetMem only 100 Bytes.
Also you might remove the "var" statements in methods vbRead and vbWrite.

Comment: with no var VbWrite result access violation

Comment: So this means that VbRead is working now?